# When running code in simulator everything works fine, but not when I run on my phone

Tags: ios, swift

When I run my app in my phone, I get this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

the error is on this line of code

```
let timeDifference = userCleander.dateComponents(calendarComponents, from: startTime, to: endTime!)
```

but it works in the simulator.. ?

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let userCleander = Calendar.current;
let calendarComponents : Set<Calendar.Component> = [
    Calendar.Component.year,
    Calendar.Component.month,
    Calendar.Component.day,
    Calendar.Component.hour
]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    timer.fire()

    printTime()
}
@objc func printTime()
{
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    let startTime = Date()
    let endTime = formatter.date(from: "10/08/19 12:00:00 a")

    let timeDifference = userCleander.dateComponents(calendarComponents, from: startTime, to: endTime!)

    TimerLable.text = "\(timeDifference.year!) År | \(timeDifference.month!) MND | \(timeDifference.day!) Dager | \(timeDifference.hour!) Timer "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this can be if endTime is nil. Since endtime is of type Date? it can be nil, and you're force unwrapping it, thus promising the compiler that it won't be nil.You should only do this if you're absolutely sure that it cannot be nil. I copied your code in an empty xcode project and it compiles and runs on iphone 7. Just to test it you could change the endtime definition to this:

```
guard let endTime = formatter.date(from: "10/08/19 12:00:00 a") else {return}
```

which prevents the crash but also prevents the app from functioning properly if the value is nil. I would suggest setting a breakpoint on timeDifference line and see the value of endTime. If it's nil try changing the locale settings on your phone (if it's not on English with Gregorian calendar try setting it to see if it makes a difference).

btw. calling timer.fire() is not necessary to start it, only if you want to fire it outside of the schedule.